# Windows restarts itself and then freezes

Tags: windows, boot, windows-10, reboot

The box restarts itself, regularly, and then freezes on the startup animation. 
Roughly like this image:

[image: startup animation]

It spins for a little while and then freezes mid spin. This also happens if the computer is deliberately restarted. The only way to get back to Windows is to hold the power button, shut the computer off completely, then turn it back on cold.

There are two things that need to get fixed here:

1. The system should not arbitrarily restart.
2. The system should restart successfully.

I've looked at the System Event Logs, but there are not many clues.

```
- <Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
- <System>
  <Provider Name="Microsoft-Windows-Kernel-Power" Guid="{331C3B3A-2005-44C2-AC5E-77220C37D6B4}" /> 
  <EventID>41</EventID> 
  <Version>3</Version> 
  <Level>1</Level> 
  <Task>63</Task> 
  <Opcode>0</Opcode> 
  <Keywords>0x8000200000000002</Keywords> 
  <TimeCreated SystemTime="2015-12-20T19:49:28.181345600Z" /> 
  <EventRecordID>4653</EventRecordID> 
  <Correlation /> 
  <Execution ProcessID="4" ThreadID="8" /> 
  <Channel>System</Channel> 
  <Computer>Insanoflex</Computer> 
  <Security UserID="S-1-5-18" /> 
  </System>
- <EventData>
  <Data Name="BugcheckCode">0</Data> 
  <Data Name="BugcheckParameter1">0x0</Data> 
  <Data Name="BugcheckParameter2">0x0</Data> 
  <Data Name="BugcheckParameter3">0x0</Data> 
  <Data Name="BugcheckParameter4">0x0</Data> 
  <Data Name="SleepInProgress">0</Data> 
  <Data Name="PowerButtonTimestamp">0</Data> 
  <Data Name="BootAppStatus">0</Data> 
  </EventData>
  </Event>
```

Is the most direct event tied to the incident, but I'm fairly sure that it occurs *after* Windows has started back up.

Prior to that I see three events frequently:

```
- <Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
- <System>
  <Provider Name="Application Popup" Guid="{47bfa2b7-bd54-4fac-b70b-29021084ca8f}" EventSourceName="Application Popup" /> 
  <EventID Qualifiers="49156">56</EventID> 
  <Version>0</Version> 
  <Level>2</Level> 
  <Task>0</Task> 
  <Opcode>0</Opcode> 
  <Keywords>0x80000000000000</Keywords> 
  <TimeCreated SystemTime="2015-12-20T19:49:15.576708700Z" /> 
  <EventRecordID>4647</EventRecordID> 
  <Correlation /> 
  <Execution ProcessID="4" ThreadID="264" /> 
  <Channel>System</Channel> 
  <Computer>Insanoflex</Computer> 
  <Security /> 
  </System>
- <EventData>
  <Data /> 
  <Data>PCI</Data> 
  <Data>010101010101010100</Data> 
  <Binary>000000000300280000000000380004C000000000380004C000000000000000000000000000000000</Binary> 
  </EventData>
  </Event>
```

and

```
- <Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
- <System>
  <Provider Name="Microsoft-Windows-DistributedCOM" Guid="{1B562E86-B7AA-4131-BADC-B6F3A001407E}" EventSourceName="DCOM" /> 
  <EventID Qualifiers="0">10010</EventID> 
  <Version>0</Version> 
  <Level>2</Level> 
  <Task>0</Task> 
  <Opcode>0</Opcode> 
  <Keywords>0x8080000000000000</Keywords> 
  <TimeCreated SystemTime="2015-12-20T16:38:58.695290300Z" /> 
  <EventRecordID>4620</EventRecordID> 
  <Correlation /> 
  <Execution ProcessID="1092" ThreadID="1128" /> 
  <Channel>System</Channel> 
  <Computer>Insanoflex</Computer> 
  <Security UserID="S-1-5-18" /> 
  </System>
- <EventData>
  <Data Name="param1">{784E29F4-5EBE-4279-9948-1E8FE941646D}</Data> 
  </EventData>
  </Event>
```

and

```
- <Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
- <System>
  <Provider Name="Application Popup" Guid="{47bfa2b7-bd54-4fac-b70b-29021084ca8f}" EventSourceName="Application Popup" /> 
  <EventID Qualifiers="49156">56</EventID> 
  <Version>0</Version> 
  <Level>2</Level> 
  <Task>0</Task> 
  <Opcode>0</Opcode> 
  <Keywords>0x80000000000000</Keywords> 
  <TimeCreated SystemTime="2015-12-20T16:35:22.576597300Z" /> 
  <EventRecordID>4570</EventRecordID> 
  <Correlation /> 
  <Execution ProcessID="4" ThreadID="260" /> 
  <Channel>System</Channel> 
  <Computer>Insanoflex</Computer> 
  <Security /> 
  </System>
- <EventData>
  <Data /> 
  <Data>PCI</Data> 
  <Data>010101010101010100</Data> 
  <Binary>000000000300280000000000380004C000000000380004C000000000000000000000000000000000</Binary> 
  </EventData>
  </Event>
```

I've tried turning off automatic updates, and fast boot among other voodoo.

Here is my build information:

[image]

Please help, my poor system is very sick.

Comment: What devices, specifically USB devices, are physically attached to your computer when it freezes during the boot process?

Comment: Lots, camera card reader, oculus rift, mouse and keyboard, apple cinema display, wacom tablet, apc power chute. All normal though.

Answer (score 0):

Your Wacom tablet is almost certainly what's causing the startup freeze. Remove it from the USB port and you will see the dots continue to spin. Once Windows passes that first boot screen, you can plug the tablet back in.

Source: experience.

Comment: Ok, I will try that! Thank you! Also, how can I figure out why the restarts are occuring?

Comment: @Fresheyeball I'm still working on that; I'll update my answer if/when I find something.

Comment: I've unplugged everything usb and it still freezes on restart.